# Rails - How to model object privacy settings and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Forms created by Users. Every form is only visible to the creator. I would like to grant permission to other users to see a specific form. One could say I want to whitelist other users for a specific form.

Here's what I tried by creating a third model called "SharedForm".

**app/models/form.rb**

```
Class Form < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :forms
  has_many :forms, through: :sharedforms
  ...
end
```

**app/models/shared_form.rb**

```
Class SharedForm < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :form
  ...
end
```

**migration**

```
class CreateSharedForms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]                           
  def change                                                                     
    create_table :shared_forms do |t|                                            
     t.integer :form_id, index: true                                            
     t.integer :user_id, index: true                                            
     t.timestamps                                                               
    end                                                                          
    add_foreign_key :shared_forms, :users, column: :user_id                      
    add_foreign_key :shared_forms, :forms, column: :form_id                      
  end                                                                            
end
```

In order to present both user forms and forms shared with the user I defined the index as:

**app/controllers/forms_controller.rb**

```
Class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @forms = Form.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    shared = SharedForm.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @sharedforms = Form.where(id: shared)
  end
end
```

This doesn't work.

Is there a way to access the records I need by user.forms and user.sharedforms respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same name for two associations as the latter will overwrite the former:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :forms
  # this overwrites the previous line!
  has_many :forms, through: :sharedforms
  ...
end
```

Instead you need to give each association a unique name:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :forms
  has_many :shared_forms
  has_many :forms_shared_with_me, through: :shared_forms
end
```

Note that the `through` option for `has_many` should point to an association on the model!

This would let you use:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @forms = current_user.forms
    @shared = current_user.forms_shared_with_me
  end
end
```

Comment: Usually you would use roles (Rolify) together with a authorization library (CanCanCan or Pundit) to handle real world applications.

Comment: you're the boss! that was perfect with a small tweak, I had to define the source.

Comment: "has_many :forms_shared_with_me, through: :shared_forms, source: :form"